# How to open camera using Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to open camera from NDK to enhance the performances and I have search several days in internet. But nothing get help.

Does anyone know how to open the camera using NDK?

Answer (score 0):

[NDK and Performance](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#native_methods):

> Native code is primarily useful when you have an existing native codebase that you want to port to Android, not for "speeding up" parts of a Java app.

Avoid jumping to the NDK because you think it'll improve performance. Stick to Java and use the [profiler](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to work out bottlenecks there.

Comment: But in profiler, we cant measure the exact time for a particular function take to execute?

Comment: No, and that's generally not the point of profiling. You profile before optimising, then try an optimisation, then profile again to compare relative speeds. It might be that your use of NDK is valid - but it might be that your Java code is inefficient. If you post the code that you think is slow, we can see what could be done.

Comment: sorry,I noticed that the problem was associated with camera, not all about ndk,I downvoted without thinking...so please edit your answer once,I will remove this vote